# ASP.NET C# Ajax Call Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm going straight to the point here.

I'm trying to get the value pass from my ajax to controller and console.log the value. however, when I try to console.log the value it gives me error 500..

here's my code:

I've been doing ajax on php for a long time.. however, I'm still new to asp.net C# mvc so please bear with me.

**AJAX:**

```
$("#Property_ProvinceID").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var province_id = $this.val();
    var $url = "/Property/GetCities";
    alert("get:" + province_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:{id: province_id},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetCities(int id)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

here's the error I don't know what's wrong with my controller though.

> POST `http://localhost:43969/Property/GetCities` 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

Comment: Does it really hit your GetCities action? Put a break point to check. Also check if you have any ActionFilterAttribute, the error may occur in there.

Comment: @KimHoang I really am positive that the method `GetCities` is existing inside my PropertyController class.... I don't know why it won't work though.. the code seems good to me..

Comment: One more guess could be the value of your province_id, it may be null or not an invalid integer. I just can suggest that based on information in your question.

Comment: @KimHoang I alert it before I pass it to the controller and the id is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if using `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` then use `JSON.stringify` to convert the data being sent to a JSON string.

```
$("#Property_ProvinceID").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var province_id = $this.val();
    var $url = "/Property/GetCities";
    alert("get:" + province_id);
    var data  = JSON.stringify({id: province_id});
    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

As mentioned in the comments by @StephenMuecke

> It does not need to be stringified if `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`, is removed (so that it uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`).

Comment: thanks for this.. so I need to stringify it first... I though `{id : province}` will suffice.

Comment: `{id : province}` on its own is a javascript value. You need to convert it to JSON.

Comment: Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: It does not need to be stringified if `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` is removed (so that it uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`). And `[FromBody]` is for web-api which this question does not appear to be about?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the clarification. will update.

Answer (score 0):

you can add error function to check for possible error on your ajax.

Ex.

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
   var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
   alert(err.Message);
}
```